# return all the letters that occur before the first number in a string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, preg-replace

I am trying to retrieve the first one or two letters from the outcode part of a postcode. The outcode can be in the format **X**1, **XX**11, **XX**1X, **X**1X. What I would like to do is to retrieve the bold part of these outcodes.

I am using a solution thus far which takes the first two characters of the string and then removes the numbers from the result:

PHP:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', substr($outcode, 0, 2));
```

JavaScript:

```
outcode.substr(0, 2).replace(/\d+/g, '')
```

This works fine, yet I wonder if there is a more efficient way in PHP and JavaScript/jQuery, such as finding the first number in the string and removing it and everything else after it? I have about 3000 outcodes to filter and efficiency is key. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Based on some comments, here are some real life examples, with desired results. Remember that the outcode string is only in one of the formats shown above, no other format:

EX13 => EX

EC2M => EC

E1W => E

E2 => E

Comment: Can you provide some more realistic input strings and what you want to extract from them? Presumably, it can be very easily achieved with a regex.

Comment: "and removing it and everything else after it" - what do you mean? how should go replacement for this string `sdfs 1111fgfg  gg55hhh7 dfgdfg` ?

Comment: Something like [`^X{1,2}`](https://regex101.com/r/bJ6nQ8/1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works well

```
"XX01XX".split(/[0-9]/)[0];
"XX".split(/[0-9]/)[0];
```

Add `.slice(0,2)` to get the first chars

Comment: the javascript code works very well, significantly more succinct thank you. Now I see what you've done, which is to split the outcode before the first number and extract the first part, I'll see if I can code the PHP equivalent.

Comment: mplungjan, I used outcode.split(/[0-9]/)[0] and I got the desired result, i.e the letters before the first number. Now I see your edit, to add slice I'm confused because I  haven't needed this. Can you please explain?

Comment: If you have 3 letters and only need the first 2?

Comment: ok I see, but fortunately I will not be presented with a string such a XXX1^. It will either be XX1^ or X1^.

Comment: ok great thanks to your guidance I coded a PHP equivalent `preg_split('/[0-9]+/',$outcode)[0];`. Would you mind commenting? Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript try:

```
firstDigit = outcode.match(/\d/); will give you the first digit in the string
index = outcode.indexOf(firstDigit);
outcode.substr(0, index);
```

Comment: If there are no digits, the result is 0,-1